# TensorFlow Optimizer - Custom Gradient Problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization

I am trying to minimize a function in TensorFlow that cannot take tensors to run. To overcome this problem, I pass a tensor into the function and immediately run it to yield the value. This is illustrated here:

```
tensor = tf.Variable(11, name='x', dtype=tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer() 
sess = sess.run(init)

def Function(tensor):
    function_variable = sess.run(tensor)    ## function_variable now = 11
    # can now run function as usual passing in this integer
```

However, in doing this I cannot get the optimizer to work properly.

I have illustrated what I am trying to do, with a simple example (trying to minimize z = x^2 + y^2 + 2).

Note the gradient needs to be given as:
[ (dz/dx, x) , (dz/dy, y) ] ... aka here [ (2x, x) , (2y,y) ]

The following code works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(2, name='x', dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.Variable(3, name='y', dtype=tf.float32)
const = tf.constant(2.0, dtype=tf.float32)


def function_to_minimize(x,y, const):
    # z = x^2 + y^2 + constant
    x_real = sess.run(x)
    y_real = sess.run(y)
    const_real = sess.run(const)

    z = x_real**2 + y_real**2 + const_real
    return tf.Variable(z, name='Z', dtype=tf.float32)

def function_to_minimize_PRINT(x,y, const):
    # z = x^2 + y^2 + constant
    z = x**2 + y**2 + const
    return z

####################################################################################

###### WORKS with this
def calc_grad(x,y):
    # z = x^2 + y^2 + constant
    dz_dx = 2*x 
    dz_dy = 2*y 
    return [(dz_dx, x), (dz_dy, y)]

###### NOT working
# def calc_grad(x,y):

#     x_real = sess.run(x)
#     y_real = sess.run(y)

#     dz_dx = 2*x_real
#     dz_dx = tf.Variable(dz_dx, name='y', dtype=tf.float32)

#     dz_dy = 2*y_real 
#     dz_dy = tf.Variable(dz_dy, name='y', dtype=tf.float32)

#     return [(dz_dx, x), (dz_dy, y)]

##############################################################################################

sess =tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
z = function_to_minimize(x,y,const)


optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.55)
grads_and_vars = calc_grad(x,y)
train = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

def optimize():
    with tf.Session() as session:
        session.run(init)
        print("starting at", "x:", session.run(x), "y:", session.run(y), "z:", session.run(z))
        for step in range(10):  
            session.run(train)
            #print(session.run(grads_and_vars))
            #print("step", step, "x:", session.run(x), "y:", session.run(y), "z:", session.run(z))
            print("step", step, "x:", session.run(x), "y:", session.run(y),
                  "z:", function_to_minimize_PRINT(session.run(x),session.run(y), session.run(const)))


optimize()
```

However, I want to run the commented out section, and replace the current `calc_grad` part... But currently what I have written doesn't work. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't very helpful to possible respondents; what is the exact issue(s) you are facing with it?

Comment: `...that cannot take tensors to run.` . Then why are you using Tensorflow?